Why do we define the distance between coils in "Helmholtz coil" arrangement to be equal to radius of the coils
I see that the very definition of Helmholtz coil states that distance between the coils centred on a common axis must be equal to the radius of both of them (which are equal also).
Why is this definition important.
Wikipedia says:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil#Description
But I don't really understand what those partial derivatives are trying to say on the wikipedia page.
Also what is a magnetic field gradient. I'm asking this because, apparently Helmholtz coil creates a region of nearly uniform magnetic field gradient when the currents in both its coils are in opposite directions.
Any help is appreciated.

You should know, that the derivatives give the change of B in direction x. And the gradient is the change in a direction.

This is a supplement to the answer by @PhilipWood.
An interactive graph can help you visualize what is happening.
Here's what I wrote for my class.

Helmholtz Coils (robphy) - superposition
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qbszpfbdgr
For one loop of radius $R$ and current, here's the field strength (dashed) and its derivative (dotted):

Including an identical loop and oriented-current but translated along the axis by a distance $R$,
we have, by superposition,

For the best uniform field near the midpoint,
we want the flattest graph of $B_z$ near the midpoint.

Notice how flat the derivative $\frac{dB_z}{dz}$ is near the midpoint of the loop-centers.
For identical loops and currents, by symmetry, regardless of the separation, at the midpoint, the odd derivatives are zero.

The first derivative being zero says $B_z$ is a local extremum.
Although the third derivative is zero, the second-derivative is not generally zero. It turns out (by calculation) that, at the midpoint, the second-derivative is zero when the separation is equal to $R$. (When this is achieved, you have to go to the 4th derivative to get something nonzero.)


Play around by changing [by dragging control points] the separation between the centers
[and by changing the radii] to see a sub-optimal configuration.

Here it is with separation $0.9R$.
$B_z$ still looks approximately constant near the midpoint, but not as good as when the separation is $R$.

Similarly, with the desmos visualization I wrote,
you could also study

the setup for an optimal uniform-gradient by flipping the direction of one current. (You have to open the "derivatives" folder and display the plot of the second-derivative... then zoom out to appreciate the variations.)
the setup for the Maxwell coil.


A graph of |magnetic flux density|, $B$, along the axis of a circular coil against displacement, $z$, from the centre of the coil is a bell-shaped curve (though not a Gaussian curve) with its maximum at $z=0$).
For two identical coaxial coils carrying equal currents in the same sense, the resultant B will be roughly constant for a short distance either side of X, a point on the axis midway between the coils. This is because at X itself $\frac{dB}{dz}$ for one coil will be equal and opposite to $\frac{dB}{dz}$ for the other coil. [We have arbitrarily chosen $z=0$ to be at the centre of one of the coils.]
My last paragraph holds whatever the separation of the coils. But when we stray along the axis from X itself, in general $\left|\frac{dB}{dz}\right|$ will be different for the two coils so the change in B from one will not exactly cancel the change in B due to the other. BUT the cancellation will be much better if $\frac{dB}{dz}$ doesn't change much if we stray. So we choose X such that $\frac{d_2B}{dz^2}$ is zero for each coil. It turns out that $\frac{d_2B}{dz^2}=0$ is at a point along the coil axis half a coil radius from the coil centre.
